# Aligning multiple imgs which have z-index with span

Tags: html, css

Im trying to create a feature similar to the "Liked by Bob and others" on Instagram:

[image]

I have nearly created this, but I'm struggling to get the images and text to align correctly: at the moment I am using absolute positioning and manually trying to center the second image with top (I tried to use vertical-align but it didn't work) but there must be something I'm doing wrong.

Also because I'm using absolute positioning, the text "Seen by Bob and 4 others" doesnt line up with the images. I tried margin-left but that doesnt work.

Any tips or tricks on what I'm doing wrong would be great! :)

```css
.readBy {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.readBy img {
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}

.readBy-img-primary {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: #fff 3px solid;
  z-index: 1;
}

.readBy-img-secondary {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 25px;
}

.readBy-img-secondary span {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.readBy-img-secondary span a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="readBy">
  <img class="readBy-img-primary" src="https://www.rd.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/01-shutterstock_476340928-Irina-Bg.jpg" alt="" />
  <img class="readBy-img-secondary" src="https://www.rd.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/01-shutterstock_476340928-Irina-Bg.jpg" alt="" />
  <span>Seen by <a href="#">Bob</a> and 4 others</span>
</div>
```

Comment: ether change the structure and put images in one div and text in another, or give text padding-left equal to images width

Comment: You can easily achieve this with flexbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display: flex` on the container with the following settings and  negative `margin-left` and `z-index`-values on the secondary image:

```css
.readBy {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.readBy img {
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}

.readBy-img-primary {
  border: #fff 3px solid;
}

.readBy-img-secondary {
   margin-left: -15px;
   z-index:-1;
}
 
.readBy span {
   margin-left: 10px;
}

.readBy-img-secondary span a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="readBy">
  <img class="readBy-img-primary" src="https://www.rd.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/01-shutterstock_476340928-Irina-Bg.jpg" alt="" />
  <img class="readBy-img-secondary" src="https://www.rd.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/01-shutterstock_476340928-Irina-Bg.jpg" alt="" />
  <span>Seen by <a href="#">Bob</a> and 4 others</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use flex to make them vertically center, and don't use position absolute on images, In this example I have used CSS's `:not` selector, so no matter how much images you want to show here, just put them and they will align as per your need.
Background color on main parent is for demo purpose only, you can remove it

```css
.readBy {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: flex; align-items: center;
  position: relative;
background: #ddd;
}

.readBy img {
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  position:relative;
}
.readBy img:not(:first-child) {transform: translateX(-50%);}

.readBy-img-secondary span a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="readBy">
  <div>
    <img class="readBy-img-primary" src="https://www.rd.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/01-shutterstock_476340928-Irina-Bg.jpg" alt="" />
    <img class="readBy-img-secondary" src="https://www.rd.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/01-shutterstock_476340928-Irina-Bg.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
  <span>Seen by <a href="#">Bob</a> and 4 others</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
.readBy-img-secondary span {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

to

```
span {
  margin-left: 60px;
}
```

also, if you don't want to hardcode this try wrapping the images in a div.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this with flexbox

Take a look at the following:

```
<div class="readBy">
  <div class="photos">
  <img class="readBy-img-primary" src="https://www.rd.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/01-shutterstock_476340928-Irina-Bg.jpg" alt="" />
  <img class="readBy-img-secondary" src="https://www.rd.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/01-shutterstock_476340928-Irina-Bg.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    Seen by all
  </div>
</div>
```

So in your css, you can just make your `readBy` a flexbox.
This will allow you to vertically align the text with `align-self`.
Your content will also be horizontally aligned.

```
.readBy{
  display: flex;
}

.readBy img {
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}

.text{
  align-self: center;
  padding-left: 10px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to use flexbox as much as I can and it is very to adapt and move around. I rather it also instead of using fixed spacing and sizing.

I added some tweaks to your css code. Check that and let me know if it does the trick.

```css
.readBy {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.images-wrapper {flex-basis: 10%}

.readBy .images-wrapper img {
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}

.readBy-img-primary {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: #fff 3px solid;
  z-index: 1;
}

.readBy-img-secondary {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 25px;
}

.readBy-img-secondary span {
  margin-left: 50px;
  flex-basis: 90% 
}

.readBy-img-secondary span a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="readBy">
  <div class="images-wrapper">
    <img class="readBy-img-primary" src="https://www.rd.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/01-shutterstock_476340928-Irina-Bg.jpg" alt="" />
    <img class="readBy-img-secondary" src="https://www.rd.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/01-shutterstock_476340928-Irina-Bg.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
  <span>Seen by <a href="#">Bob</a> and 4 others</span>
</div>
```